# How to manage no of node in taxonomy page?

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-taxonomy

I am developing site using Drupal7 with JD Fashion theme from [Joomlart](http://www.joomlart.com/)

I have created one vocabulary and terms it in the taxonomy.I have use this terms for menu navigation and added some stories(node) for each menu item.

In post setting I have kept no of nodes in main page to 3 using admin/content management/post setting.

But it is only working for home page and not for inner pages.

I want to restrict the no of nodes to 3.

1. How can i do that?
2. Is their any module or extension for pagination to control no of article per page?

Answer (score 2):

You can turn on the **Taxonomy Term** view in the Views UI to have more control over the taxonomy pages. This view is automatically generated by the Taxonomy module, but is disabled by default.

Once turned on you can set the Pager in the Page setting area to **Display a specified number of items** and set the numer of Items per page to the desired number.

This will limit the number of nodes displayed in the Taxonomy pages.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this without views. 
The number of nodes displayied in taxonomy page is determined by the `default_nodes_main` variable, that also controls, the n° of nodes in the home page and the number of blog posts.

You can adjust that at **admin/config/system/site-information** > front page > n° of nodes in front page.

So, beware of side effects. I made a search in all of the D7 code and i found out that `default_nodes_main` appears in

- blog.pages.inc:26
- blog.pages.inc:66, **limiting the number of post**
- node.module:2601, **limiting the number of sticky nodes** (front page)
- taxonomy_pages.inc:55, **limiting number of nodes in the taxonomty page**

Known the consequences, you can use that setting.